# Foreign key relation in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, foreign-keys

I know this question has been asked before many times but, I still can't solve it.

**model.py**

```
class Awb (models.Model):
    awb_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    awb_shipment_date = models.DateTimeField()
    awb_shipper = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    awb_sender_contact = models.CharField(max_length= 50)

class History (models.Model):
    history_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    awb = models.ForeignKey(Awb)
    history_city_hub = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    history_name_receiver = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

**view.py**

```
def awb_list_view(request):
    data = {}
    data['awb'] = Awb.objects.all()
    data['history'] = History.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'portal/awb-list.html', data)
```

**templates**

```
{% for s in awb.history_set.all %}
    {{ s.awb_id }}
    {{ s.history_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

When I tried it with this code, there was no results in templates. I want to show awb_id and history_id in templates. Could you help me?

Comment: Hi Benz, first get all records from awb objects in view and after search history id with the help of awb object id. If you find history id then store both awb id and history id in dict as key, value format and pass it in render. After in template iterate it. :)

Answer (score 4):

First let's take a look at the view code...

```
def awb_list_view(request):
    data = {}
    data['awb'] = Awb.objects.all()
    data['history'] = History.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'portal/awb-list.html', data)
```

The context dictionary being passed to the template contains an item with key 'awb' and respective QuerySet `Awb.objects.all()`.

Now let's take a look at the template for loop...

```
{% for s in awb.history_set.all %}
```

This opening for loop template tag is trying to produce a reverse set of History objects.  In order to achieve this, we would need a single AWB object instance.  Instead, the 'awb' variable is a QuerySet which was passed as context to the template.

If the goal of this code is to show all AWB objects with their related History objects, the following template code should be valid.

```
{% for awb_obj in awb %}
    {% for history_obj in awb_obj.history_set.all %}
        {{ awb_obj.id }}
        {{ history_obj.id }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Awb.history_set.all only applies to one Awb object, not a queryset.

This would work:

```
data['awb'] = Awb.objects.first()  # If the first one has history
```

or:

Loop through all the Awb objects in the template to access the history_set for each one.

```
{% for a in awb %}
    awb: {{ a.awb_id }}<br>
    {% for h in a.history_set.all %}
        history: {{ h.history_id }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Original code:

```
{% for s in awb.history_set.all %}
    {{ s.awb_id }}
    {{ s.history_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Corrected code

```
{% for awb in awb %}
    AWB ID: {{ awb.awb_id }}
    {% for history in awb.history_set.all %}
        History ID: {{ history.history_id }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).