# Django 3: Adding Data to DetailView

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-3.0

I have a very similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399586/django-set-all-filter-not-working-in-template) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613814/foreign-key-relation-in-django-template) and my guess is I overlooked something.

I want to query related objects (foreign keys) from the model in the template:

**models.py:**

```
class PartBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField("Price per part", decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)       

class Sett(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=120)

class PartRelation(models.Model):
    part = models.ForeignKey(PartBase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.PositiveIntegerField("Quantity")
    sett = models.ForeignKey(Sett, related_name='setts', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

**views.py:**

```
class SetDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Sett
    context_object_name = "setts"
```

**template:**

```
{% for p in setts.partrelation_set.all %}
  <p>value: {{ p.get_part_price }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**Problem:** empty HTML page - so setts.partrelation_set.all is empty / does not exist.

What I tried was adding a queryset to the view class:

```
class SetDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Sett
    context_object_name = "setts"
    queryset = Sett.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(setts = self.kwargs.get("Sett_id"))
```

But I took a wrong turn here somewhere.
What I also tried is adding a lot of return attribute methods in the model and so I could get it to work in the shell - but not in the DetailView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `related_name` to call the child objects

```
{% for p in setts.setts.all %}
  <p>value: {{ p.get_part_price }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**

better to remove the context object name and call

```
{% for p in object.setts.all %}
  <p>value: {{ p.get_part_price }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: context object remove because of the awkward naming `setts.setts.all`? Thanks, that did the trick!